# Flutterwave payment integration

Tags: flutterwave

1)Can I create a customer without an email address but by using a phone number in flutter wave payment integration?
2)Is it possible to do a recurring subscription without using a flutter wave API

Comment: Asking more than one question is considered a hard to answer because unfocused question.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, You can pass email values containing the user's phone details in the request payload. The domain of the email is what is validated to ensure we are not spammed.

Here is a sample format you can use to create emails for your users - `user's_phone_number@your_domain`. Please feel free to explore other similar formats.